# Why won't text input box appear?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to break things down into components.  Inside my `App.js` file, I would like to see the text input box that would come about from the `<CreateAccount/>` component.  The problem is that it's giving me an error.  As soon as I include `<View></View>`, my background disappears (just have a white screen) and I see `Email` (from `placeholder`) on the top left corner of my physical device.

I want to have the text input box directly underneath the title `My App`.  This whole React Native thing is so different from regular HTML & CSS so I'm wondering why this is happening in my case and what can I do to fix it?

Here's `App.js` file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import BackGround from './components/BackGround';
import CreateAccount from './components/CreateAccount';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <BackGround/>
                <CreateAccount/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Here's `BackGround.js` file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Image, Text} from 'react-native';

export default class BackGround extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Image style={styles.container} source={require('../pictures/smoke.jpg')}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>My App</Text>
            </Image>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: null,
        height: null,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    },

    title: {
        paddingBottom: 390,
        fontSize: 50
    }
});
```

Here's `CreateAccount` file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

export default class CreateAccount extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <TextInput
                placeholder={"Email"}
                placeholderTextColor={"#f44242"}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add CreateAccount to Background if you want the input to fall within the image. Images also have a prop for image size `resizeMode={'cover'} `. I would add `flex: 1` to `View` in App. The parents of flexbox elements should be flex elements themselves.

Comment: @Matty Thank you!  This works for me.